# Solr indexing process: keep a persistent Mysql connection throu all the indexing process

Tags: plugins, jdbc, indexing, solr, database-connection

I wrote my custom update handler for my solr installation, using jdbc to query a mysql database. Everything works fine: the updater queries the db, gets the data i need and update it in my documents! Fantastic!

Only issue is i have to open and close a mysql connection for every document i read. Since we have something like 10kk indexed document, i was thinking about opening a mysql connection at the very beginning of the indexing process, keeping it stored somewhere and use it inside my custom update handler. When the whole indexing process is complete, the connection should be closed.

So far, is it possible?

Comment: How come you didn't look at the DataImportHandler approach?

Comment: it doesn't fit my needs (as i understood). i don't need to import the full mysql database into my solr. in solr i have documents with "raw location strings", in mysql i have full location hierarchy (contry -> region -> city) and i use it just to improve my base entry. Example: in document "mary lives in london" -> query the db for "london" -> save in solr europe, gb, london. so i tought an update handler would have fitted my needs best...